# ¿Cómo actualizar mi aplicación web sin que queden restos de caché?

Tags: .htaccess, cache

Supongamos que tengo una página web que tiene dos archivos `index.html` e `index.js`, los cuales tienen esta política de caché en mi archivo `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    <FilesMatch "\.(html?|js)$">
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 4 days"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Ahora necesito actualizar esos dos archivos, pero actualizarlos puede ocasionar errores por la página web que tienen mis usuarios guardada en caché que no cambiará hasta que el periodo establecido culmine, haciéndolos ver una versión vieja de mi página; y no sé cómo evitar esos problemas.

¿Alguien me puede decir cómo cambio mi contenido evitando que sea reemplazado por la versión en caché de mis usuarios? ¿Hay alguna manera de obligar a los navegadores a borrar la caché de mi sitio web?
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para empezar yo no pondria nunca los html en una regla así, pues no sabria realmente la cantidad de visualizaciones que han tenido, aun siendo de la misma IP.

Si te refieres a los **js** es más facil de solucionar, simplemente cambiales el nombre y los enlaces que tenias que apunten al nuevo nombre, y en 7 dias lo vuelves a hacer dejandolos como estaban si quieres.

Otro truco que se usa es meterles una coletilla que represente algo, una fecha o un codigo de version o algo, tipo `script.js?12345` y así siempre van a ir a la versión correcta.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo. Será un poco tedioso, pero lo probaré. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Lo de la coletilla hazlo automático, solo cuando hagas cambios, y no tienes que hacer nada en los scripts, se van a cargar igual, pero van a volver a buscarlos si les cambia el numero... Si te fijas en muchos enlaces de muchos sitios lo hacen asi para los js o css (creo que wordpress y/o magento lo hacen asi, por ejemplo).